# Does gradle support "promotion" of errors?

Tags: gradle, continuous-integration, findbugs

Our setup uses git/gerrit for code review, and we also have a "verification" build there: you can only submit your patch set when the verification build passes.

The problem is: we have several activities that are not part of the verification build, only the nightly full build runs. For example to run `findbugs`. So it can easily happen that findbugs finds a "must address" bug.

We can't add findbugs to the verification build (as that would take too miuch time). But I also don't want to *immediately* fail on the nightly build.

Now I am wondering: does gradle have support for handling errors differently over time?

As in:

- the first time such a "must address" issue pops up, the nightly build only sends an email to the person touching the corresponding file
- the second time, that mail goes also to the manager of that person
- and maybe the third night, the build fails

Would we have to implement such "stateful" error handling ourselves, or does gradle support this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that the question more likely relates to the CI-server configuration, rather than Gradle build configuration.

Though it is possible to set the `ignoreFailures` property of the `findbugs` task, to prevent your build from imeddiately fail, and then CI server have to analyze some way this build and may be some build history and make a decision, what to do next.

The thing is that Gralde doesn't know anything about previously runned builds and does not have any out-of-the-box solution for that, since the build history is in the scope of the CI server, which can event create a new temporary workspace for every Gradle build.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I will wait some time, but when nothing better comes in, I will accept your answer.